# Java servlet how to disable caching of page

Tags: java, servlets

How to disable caching ?

What headers should doGet set?

Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Here is a good article about the subject: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index2.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will set caching to disabled on the response:

```
// Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

// Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Comment: I believe you would like to add
`response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);`
for proxies. See another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413036/http-response-caching)

Comment: Which servlet should we write this code into? the one that is redirecting to the html page keeping the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I want to disabled the varnish cache if backend server return some header

eg.

if is set header like follow

JAVA code

```
ServletActionContext.getResponse().addHeader("ABC","true")
```

then in varnish  if I found value of header ABC as true then I don't want to cache this page.