# Why cache-control is not set but presented in response header?

Tags: java, http-headers

I didn't set `cache-control` in anywhere in my code , and wondering why there is the still the `cache-control` shown in my response header?

Answer (score 0):

The `cache-control` you see is inserted by default. Websites must have a cache control.

If you want to control it [check here](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/), but if you **DON'T want** to catch anything, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413036/http-response-caching).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because you use a framework which adds a filter to set those headers (if you use Spring or Spring Security, they will add those headers, for example). Since you don't give more information, there is no better answer.

Comment: I am using the apache wicket with jetty, even if I set the header cache-control in the code, it didn't override the original one..