# Prevent browser from caching session id

Tags: html

I am trying to make our web application more secure. So, want to prevent browser from caching session id of the application.

Our index.html already has meta tags as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache, no-store">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

But, this is not just sufficient.

Tried to include some other meta tags like:

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

but not able to achieve it.

Can any one help me with some other possible solution.

Comment: Gangadhar, when you say "but not able to achieve it", what do you mean? What's the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

please try setting response on server side.
In java you can write this

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
    response.setBufferSize(0);
```

Also, please refer here([HTTP response caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413036/http-response-caching))